# Make :first-child ignore nested structure?

Tags: css, css-selectors

http://jsfiddle.net/RKwHk/
How do I need to change my selector so that it only selects the first paragraph? Thanks

```
<div class="cont">
    <span>
        <p>first</p>
    </span>
     <span>
        <p>second</p>
    </span>
     <span>
        <p>thrid</p>
    </span>
</div>

.cont p {
    color: green;
}
.cont p:first-child {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: select span as first child not paragraph

Comment: Why do you have `p` elements in `span` elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it this way:

```
.cont p {
    color: green;
}
.cont span:first-child p {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

```
.cont div:first-of-type p, /* or the following */
.cont div:first-child p {
    color: red;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/RKwHk/1/).

Note that I've changed the `span` elements to `div` elements, since a `p` should not be contained within an inline element.

Answer (score 0):

will 100% working  Use this one

```
.cont p {
    color: green;
}

.cont span:first-child p{
   color:Red;
}
```